# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in

Tags: curl

I am using,

PHP version 7.0.8

I have enabled php_curl module as well. I checked in php.ini for confirming and it is uncommented as below.

```
;extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_dba.dll
```

Comment: you still need to check if the module was actually LOADED by php, e.g. check `phpinfo()`. the .ini itself doesn't mean much, just that php CAN load it, if everything works out ok.

Comment: cURL Support is not enable what i do ?

Comment: start debugging, then. check error logs and whatnot to see why it's not loading.

Comment: stop hiding errors. you have `display_startup_errors=false` so you dont see the error the curl module gets during initialization. why would you hide the error, then ask why its not working? the error you're explicitly hiding is there to tell you that exact thing, and until you show us the error, we don't know that the problem is either

Comment: what's in your `log_errors` and `error_log` directive in php.ini ?

Answer (score 0):

the problem was with dll files

```
;extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_dba.dll
```

were off I set them on in apache2/php.ini

```
enable_dl = On
```

I read a lot about extension=php_curl.dll to remove ; but no one  say to enable the dll hope i help someone with the answer